# Modulus of Rigidity (Shear Modulus) of string

Tags: materials

Does anybody know of what magnitude should the Modulus Of Rigidity of a wool string should be? I know that neither wool or string are "materials" but if anybody can give me a rough estimate of a value I would be very thankful.

Comment: The Young's modulus is around 1.4 GPa and the Poisson's ratio is around 0.35.  You can compute the shear modulus from these.  The values are for the linear regime only.

Comment: Also something like a string is not isotropic. The shear modulus is probably not calculated in the same way as the isotropic material counterparts. I am interested in what application you would need this value? A string doesn't seem to show much shear rigidity at all....